# Words go out of the borders in d3.js tag cloud

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tag-cloud

I want to create word tag cloud using d3 .. I found a good example [here](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) but the problem that the words go outside the borders especially in case of large fonts and this screenshot for the problem
[image]

and here's my code

```
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script>
var fill = d3.scale.category20();

d3.layout.cloud().size([600, 600])
    .words([
        "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
        "than", "this"
    ].map(function(d) {
        return {
            text: d,
            size: 10 + Math.random() * 90
        };
    }))
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function() {
        return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90;
    })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) {
        return d.size;
    })
    .on("end", draw)
    .start();

function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 700)
        .attr("height", 700)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) {
            return d.size + "px";
        })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return fill(i);
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.text;
        });
}
</script>
```

anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the following line in `draw()`:

```
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
```

to:

```
        .attr("transform", "translate(350,350)")
```

Since your SVG's size is 700x700, you want the g transform to be in the middle of the SVG as the text elements are anchored in the middle.

Comment: I already find this solution form 3 days ago but I forgot to answer it. thanks for your answer :)